# i want to get CNN news article all link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-newspaper

i want to get CNN news article all link

for example

in this link

```
  https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10
```

i can show lastest 10 news

to get news link 
i tried two methods.

```
   html_page = urlopen(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

   cnn_paper = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)  # ~15 seconds
   n_list = []
   for article in cnn_paper.articles:
      n_list.append(article.url)
```

and

```
req = Request(url)
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

but i can`t get news link

If you go to the next page, i can only get the same link

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.